# What is wrong is my code?

Tags: python-2.7

```
myfile = open('samplefile.txt')
for line in myfile:
    item = line.split(',')
    songnumber = input("Please enter the number: ")
    if item[0] == songnumber:
        title = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20} {5:20}'.format('Song number', 'Song date', 'Player 1 nickname', 'Player 2 nickname', 'Played?', 'Winning Nickname')
        print(title)
        result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20} {5:20}'.format(item[0],item[1],item[3],item[4],item[5],item[6])
        print(result)
```

1. 1,20/12/16,zombiechow,ysera,Y,ysera
2. 2,21/12/16,ysera,grommer,Y,grommer
3. theres more

Hi there still I'm still new to python, recently I just learned how to open a file and split the lines in it. So as stated in the subject, I'm stuck I was trying out the code above and I wanted to print the songnumber = 27 the return I got was the same question for input again. It doesn't work unless I entered in the code from 1 -27, only I can get the right answer. What mistake did i make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make item[0] as integer or songnumber as string and fix IndexError!

Comment: thats what i'm curious to know what mistake did i make to get IndexError?

Comment: dudE! where is item[2] in result?